# Is it possible to subtract x number of days from todays date in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the GetMetaData activity that returns a 'lastmodifieddate'. Is there anyway in Azure DF to take the current date (today) and then subtract 3 days from today to compare against the 'lastmodifidedate'?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anyway in Azure DF to take the current date (today) and then
>   subtract 3 days from today to compare against the 'lastmodifidedate'?

```
 @equals(formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-3),'yyyy-MM-dd'),formatDateTime(activity('Your Metadata Activity Name').output.lastmodifieddate,'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

In order to compare the dates or any value, you have to make use of Logical Function. Here the **equals** method compares two values and return boolean value. Please find more details about [logical function on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#logical-functions)

**formatDateTime** function helps us to modify the format of any datetime. Since you need to compare the date part we have made use of 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

**addDays** method helps us in adding any number of days to the datetime.

**utcNow()** method returns the current UTC date time value.

Please find complete details about functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).